# How to call a closure from a macro?

Tags: rust

What's the best way to call a closure from a macro?  Consider this code:

```
macro_rules! push_matches {
    ( $iterator: expr, $pattern: pat $(, $f: expr)? ) => {{
        for i in $iterator {
            if !matches!(i, $pattern) { break; }
            $( $f(i); )?
        }
    }}
}


fn main() {
    let mut s = vec![];
    push_matches!("abcde".chars(), 'a'..='c', |c| s.push(c));
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

The code works as expected, but clippy (since about 1.72) complains:

```
warning: try not to call a closure in the expression where it is declared
  --> src/main.rs:5:16
   |
5  |             $( $f(i); )?
   |                ^^^^^
...
13 |     push_matches!("abcde".chars(), 'a'..='c', |c| s.push(c));
   |     -------------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
```

which is fair enough, line 5 of the macro expands to `(|c| s.push(c))(i)`.  Ideally, I'd like to define the closure once, not every time through the loop, and call it at each iteration of the loop.

Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve an extra step (defining the closure on a separate line) in the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to store the closure outside of the loop with a bit of a hack.

The straightforward fix would be to conditionally declare a new variable outside of the loop and then conditionally invoke the closure.

```
macro_rules! push_matches {
    ( $iterator: expr, $pattern: pat $(, $f: expr)? ) => {{
        $( let mut f = $f; )?
        for i in $iterator {
            if !matches!(i, $pattern) { break; }
            $( f(i); )?
        }
    }};
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the compiler doesn't know how many times to run `$( f(i); )?` since we didn't specify any repeating macro argument within:

```
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
 --> src/main.rs:6:14
  |
6 |             $( f(i); )?
  |              ^^^^^^^^^
```

We can fix this by using `$f` in a no-op, which is easily done by having a "private" pattern that takes an argument and does nothing with it:

```
macro_rules! push_matches {
    ( $iterator: expr, $pattern: pat $(, $f: expr)? ) => {{
        // Suppress warning about redundant "mut" when the closure
        // doesn't mutate its environment.
        $( #[allow(unused_mut)] let mut f = $f; )?
        for i in $iterator {
            if !matches!(i, $pattern) { break; }
            $(
                push_matches!(@ignore $f);
                f(i);
            )?
        }
    }};
    
    ( @ignore $f: expr ) => {};
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92af71370a5017febee3e59dd954030c))

Comment: You still need `#[allow(unused_mut)]` here, in case it's called with a closure that doesn't need to be mutable, e.g.: `push_matches!("abcde".chars(), 'a'..='c', |c|  println!("{c}"));`

Comment: Thank you!  I got as far as the error you show above, and then got stuck, and wasn't sure that was the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can include it in the repeated block so it knows when to repeat, and then `cfg` it to never be compiled.

```rs
$(
    #[allow(unused_mut)]
    let mut f = $f;
)?
for i in $iterator {
    if !matches!(i, $pattern) { break; }
    $(
        f(i);
        #[cfg(any())]
        let _ = $f;
    )?
}
```

You can also make different branches for each one, and have the non-closure branch insert an empty closure.

```rs
( $iterator: expr, $pattern: pat, $f: expr ) => {
    #[allow(unused_mut)]
    let mut f = $f;
    for i in $iterator {
        if !matches!(i, $pattern) { break; }
        f(i);
    }
};
( $iterator: expr, $pattern: pat ) => {
    push_matches!($iterator, $pattern, |_| {})
};
```

Comment: Thank you!  The empty closure is a very elegant solution!